# Please make the Hat Dash leaderboard link a different color

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

Over at the [Winter Bash](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/) page, the link leading to the leaderboard under the Hat Dash button is not a great color and is kind of hard to read:

[image]

Especially against the orange background.  Can we make it the blue color that only shows when you hover over the link, like this:

[image]

Just uncheck the `color: #ffb75f;` box.  Or heck, make it `#3474e6`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The link in question is now a much lighter color, hopefully improved contrast.

[image: image of the section of the page in question]

> bad contrast hurts eyes
> hope link now discernable
> now go, jump for joy!