# Server error when trying to log in to Winter Bash 2020 Hat Dash after it has ended

Tags: support, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, 500-server-error

Today I found this:
[Please make the Hat Dash leaderboard link a different color](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358208/please-make-the-hat-dash-leaderboard-link-a-different-color)

And was interested to see what this is:
https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/

When I try to login, I get:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened! We apologize for any inconvenience, but
> an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site. It’s
> not you, it’s us. This is our fault. Detailed information about this
> error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

Why is this happening? I realize that Winter Bash is over, but I should not see this error message, as the team has stated that they intend to leave the site up until they begin preparations for Winter Bash 2021 in October.

PS: I also read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334179/oops-something-bad-happened), but it was not helpful.

Comment: It's over since 01/03/2021

Comment: Yeah but it should not said that error occurred.

Comment: What else would you expect should be displayed?

Comment: That the time is over and I can not login anymore. But generally why I can not login even if time is out ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've been told in chat that the site would be open at least 6 months.

Comment: The more why it is impossible to log in ?

Comment: Hmm, I can see the winterbash site quite fine... maybe since winterbash is over you can't create an account on the site.

Comment: still... I should see `That the time is over and I can not login anymore.` but not `error occurred`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The team has stated somewhere (don't remember where) that they won't be taking the WB 2020 site down until around October or so. Also, if it is intentional that it's not supposed to work, then it should display a proper error message rather than a server error.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog and this is exactly what I'm talking about. The more when I click `About this hat` then I was requested by this message `Log in to see which sites you've earned this hat on and wear it!` .... So I want to LogIn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can still log in. I think that it is something specific to your account. Please try again now, I think that it is resolved.

> Winter Bash is done
> I don't know what you want to
> Log in still active

Comment: Confirmed as fixed. What was the issue source ?